# Storing data in time range before and after threshold value is met

Tags: r, dataframe, timestamp, subset

I have a data frame that contains a column with timestamps (called "Timestamp") and a column containing air pollutant concentrations (called "value").

[image: data frame]

I have a threshold value for the air pollutant, say 11 (for example), and would like to graph concentration versus time plots for the 5 hours before the threshold is met until 24 hours after the threshold is met for all occurrences of concentrations reaching or exceeding 11.

I think I can figure out the graphing but my main issue at this point is subsetting and storing the data for the periods before and after the threshold is met. Any ideas on how I can do this?

Thanks.

Comment: Please provide an example of your data.

Comment: Actually, a data set we could copy (dput) would be easier to work with but I will try to build a minimal example.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I apologize for the following code beeing a bit confusing. However, I think it should work like this:

```
require(tidyverse)
require(lubridate)

# Create example data
timestamp <- c("2017-01-01 00:00:00", "2017-01-01 01:00:00", "2017-01-01 02:00:00",
           "2017-01-01 03:00:00", "2017-01-01 04:00:00", "2017-01-01 05:00:00",
           "2017-01-01 06:00:00", "2017-01-01 07:00:00", "2017-01-01 08:00:00",
           "2017-01-01 09:00:00", "2017-01-01 10:00:00", "2017-01-01 11:00:00")

value <- c(8, 10, 12, 13, 10, 2, 3, 6, 5, 8, 6, 7)

df <- data.frame(timestamp = ymd_hms(timestamp), value = value)

# Find incidents with values over 11
df %>%
  mutate(treshold = ifelse(value >= 11, 1, 0)) %>%
  filter(treshold == 1) %>%
  .$timestamp-> incidents

# Create new data frame to store final data
final_df <- data.frame()

# Loop over incidents and filter for relevant data points
for (i in seq(length(incidents))){
  df %>%
    filter(timestamp %in% (incidents[i] + dhours(-5:24))) %>%
    mutate(id = i) %>%
    rbind(final_df, .) -> final_df
}
```

You can now use the final data frame to create your plot. Therefore, you can filter for each incident using the `id` column.

Alternatively, you could run the following code to create a distinct plot for each incident:

```
ggplot(final_df, aes(x = timestamp, y = value)) + geom_line() + facet_wrap(~id)
```

[image: Plot]

Comment: Hi @Niko, when I attempt to run the loop I get the following error:
`Error in filter_impl(.data, quo) : 
  Evaluation error: 'match' requires vector arguments.`

Comment: Does this error happen if you use your own data or my example data?

Comment: with my own data. I read in one of my files and called it 'df' then implemented your code in sections, and the error occurred when applying the loop.

Comment: Mhm ok. I am not sure but is it possible, that your timestamp variable is not in the datetime format? I transform it with `ymd_hms(timestamp)` in the last line of my example data.

Comment: Oh wow I apologize, silly mistake on my part, "timestamp" requires an uppercase T. Code works. Thanks!